# java hello world compliation error

Tags: java

Under eclipse, Java 7

I cannot get the following to work:

```
    import java.io.Console;

    package com.company;

    public class main 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        }
    }
```

It's surprising, I've been toying around with java for a while, going back to the hello world I'd skipped I never thought it would be my hardest task yet. I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at main.main(main.java:10)
```

EDIT:
So I've gotten it to run like so:

```
import Fibonacci;

public class main 
{

    private Fibonacci f;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // System.out.println("Hello, World")
        f= new Fibonacci();
        System.out.println(Fibonacci.compute(f), 5);
    }
}
```

how do I print fibonacci's fifth element.

Comment: Swap import and package?

Comment: You're missing a closing brace.

Comment: Closing brace is missing. `package` should be 1st stmt.

Comment: Is Eclipse not pointing out you are missing a closing }? Try Ctrl-Shift-F to format the code, then the problem should be obvious.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't try to run it if it doesn't compile - and the error message should show the problem, too. (Always include the full error message in SO questions.)

Comment: i didn't grab it on the copy paste, it's actually there.

Comment: The message also shows that you're trying to *execute* the code before it *compiles*, despite the warning you got from the IDE. Don't do that. Read the error messages you get from the compiler and fix all the errors before trying to run the program.

Comment: This is a good example where formatting your code pays dividends

Comment: put your package statement above import statement and put closeing brace on it

Comment: that's the full error message, nothing else. :(

Comment: well removing the package that I picked up in another thread fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. Put the package to the first line.
2. Class name should start with big letter - also the file name should be Main with capital **M**
3. There is a } missing
4. The import is not needed, but this is not so big deal.

Try this:

```
package com.company;

//import java.io.Console; //uncomment if needed

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run code inside Eclipse which has an error. Eclipse generates code to produce that message.

You are invoking that code generated by Eclipse. Your original source was erroneous, so the Eclipse compiler could not compile it - instead byte code has been generated that shows the message in the question.

Ensure that all errors are fixed and run again.

Comment: fixed,

here's the correct code:

    public class main {
 
 
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        }
    }

The extra import and package were messing things up.

I still have an error at main(String[] args) which eclipse wants to change to constructor. but the code runs successfully

Answer (score 0):

You need  one more `}`           Ctrl+F1  will help you for errors

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Console;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import class line should be after package and remove your import line reaming code working

like

```
package com.like  //than
import java.io.Console
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code.

You cannot have import statements before the package statement.

It looks like you are missing a curly brace.

There is no reason to reference Console.

Try this...

```
// Main.java  (case is important. If the file is 
// Main.java, the class needs to be Main.)
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```